# "Call to a member function mergeWith() on a non-object" when using related queries

Tags: propel

I'm having this situation with Propel 1.6 and a MySQL database:

```
$query->usePublicationQuery("pq");
$query->condition('c1', '(YEAR(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "2013")
        ->condition('c2', '(MONTH(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "03")
        ->condition('c3', '(DAY(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "01")
        ->combine(array('c1', 'c2','c3'), 'and', 'c123');
$query->endUse();
```

The mergeWith()-error appears upon invocation of the endUse()-method. It is thrown when Propel tries to merge the queries like this in ModelCriteria.php:

```
$primaryCriteria->mergeWith($this); // (line 941)
```

$primaryCriteria seems to be null. Can anyone tell me, when and why this can possibly happen?

Comment: I think you should show us some more code. How do you initialize $primaryCriteria etc?

Comment: I don't initialize `$primaryCriteria`. It's just the line where Propel throws the error in the `ModelCriteria.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caveat is that Propel's useQuery() and endUse() methods RETURN new query rather that change current one. So, either rewrite whole query using method chaining:

```
$query
    ->usePublicationQuery("pq")
        ->condition('c1', '(YEAR(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "2013")
        ->condition('c2', '(MONTH(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "03")
        ->condition('c3', '(DAY(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "01")
        ->combine(array('c1', 'c2','c3'), 'and', 'c123')
    ->endUse();
```

...or something like this:

```
$query2 = $query->usePublicationQuery("pq");

$query2->condition('c1', '(YEAR(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "2013")
        ->condition('c2', '(MONTH(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "03")
        ->condition('c3', '(DAY(`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE`)) = ?', "01")
        ->combine(array('c1', 'c2','c3'), 'and', 'c123');

$query = $query2->endUse();
```

Comment: I came to the conclusion to use `$query->usePublicationQuery("pq")->condition('c1', '(YEAR(\`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE\`)) = ?', "2013")->condition('c2', '(MONTH(\`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE\`)) = ?', "03")->condition('c3', '(DAY(\`pq.PUBLISHED_DATE\`)) = ?', "01")->combine(array('c1', 'c2','c3'), 'and', 'c123')->endUse();` as a single statement and this always works.

Comment: Okay, you chose to use method chaining. Just remember that useBarQuery returns another Query object (otherwise you would not be able to use filterBySomeBarField-style methods, etc) and it is impossible to swap original $query FooQuery-type variable with BarQuery-type variable.

Answer (score 0):

How are you instantiating the $query variable? Are you sure you're not trying to do this:

```
  $query = PublicationQuery::create()
```

Without more information it's going to be very difficult to troubleshoot this, please provide more code.

Comment: Yep, I actually used the `create()` method to instantiate a different query, that is related to "Publication". Then I used the `PublicationQuery` as an embedded query [as described in the docs](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#embedding_a_related_query). Sorry for having taken this for granted. I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with how I formulated the conditions. Maybe it's the `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` notation that hurts Propel. The disturbing thing, though, is that the error message seems to be of no value.

Comment: Can you edit your above post and include some additional code before what you've provided above?